# Overriding model's urlRoot to a function fails

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I try to override the urlRoot attribute of a model and do a fetch on that model, the urlRoot actually returns the whole function as a string. Here is what the overridden urlRoot looks like:

```
urlRoot: function() {
  return "test";
},
```

It returns the following:
`http://localhost:8000/items/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22test%22;%20%20%20%20%7D`

Also, where does the items portion of the URL come from?

Comment: What else is going on in that model? Is there a collection involved?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/RFw4n/

Comment: As @muistooshort said, there is something we are not seeing, for example: _where is this `/items` url token coming from?_

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using? I'm not sure if older versions allow `urlRoot` to be a function.

Comment: @mu is too short, I am using the latest version of backbone. Do you think it has to do with me using backbone-tastypie? That is all I have inside of the model. I have run into many issues from backbone-tastypie in the past.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about backbone-tastypie so I can't speculate. What happens if you use just a string for `urlRoot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLRoot is expected to be a **static string**

- defined either during construction or
- during runtime

You can override the URl as a `function` if a logic lies in construction of the url.

#### Example

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

..
urlRoot:"test",
url:function(){

return this.urlRoot + "/" + this.cid;

},
..

}):
```

Comment: ["Note that `urlRoot` may also be defined as a function."](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-urlRoot)

Comment: @muistooshort that surprised me. I did try it as function did not work previously. Must be something wrong in the docs

Comment: The docs are accurate, read the source and you'll see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tjeVs/ . I wonder if there is a Backbone version issue in play here though.

Comment: the `urlRoot` value is extracted with [this function](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1439-1442) which supports both: static values and functions.

Comment: yes, URLRoot can be defined as function too. I've been using it as such for a long time now... It's surprising that this answer is marked accepted.

Comment: When linking to line numbers make sure to specify the commit! The function which @fguillen was pointing at two years ago is the `getValue` used internally in the definitions of `Model` and `View`: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/85bd0b5132e0da853eda114bd761d7961b80a146/backbone.js#L1439-1442 Backbone 1.x uses underscore's `_.result`: http://underscorejs.org/#result

Comment: Using the method supplied by @Deeptechtons works for me, however, I have been unable to successfully implement what the other commenters suggest: defining `urlRoot` as a function. When I define `urlRoot` as a function, the URL returned appends the model's ID to the very end. Any thoughts on how to get past this?